# google cloud endpoints API call returns false instead of collection

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I've made a simple google cloud endpoints API for studding puurpose and android client for it.
here is an Entyty class:

```
@Entity
public class TransactionRecord implements Serializable {
    @Id Long id;
    int price;
    String comment;

    public TransactionRecord () { }

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public int getPrice() { return price; }
    public String getComment() { return comment; }

    public void setPrice(int price) { this.price = price; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    public void setComment(String comment) { this.comment = comment; }
}
```

And one of endpoints methods which I have some troubles with:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "listTransactions")
public CollectionResponse<TransactionRecord> getTransactionsList(@Named("count") int count) {
    List<TransactionRecord> records = ofy().load().type(TransactionRecord.class).limit(count).list();
    return CollectionResponse.<TransactionRecord>builder().setItems(records).build();
}
```

Android client works well but js client returns false if I call this methoud
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var gapiReady    = false;

  function api_init() {
    console.log('api_init');

    gapiReady = true;

    var host = window.location.host;
    var protocol = host.search('localhost') == -1 ? 'https://' : 'http://';
    var ROOT = protocol + host + '/_ah/api';
    gapi.client.load('transaction', 'v1', function(){transaction_load(100);}, ROOT);
  }

  function transaction_load(limit) {
    console.log('transaction_load ' + limit);

    if (gapiReady) {
      gapi.client.transaction.listTransactions(limit).execute(function(resp) {
      console.log('listTransactions resp: ' + resp + ' code: ' + resp.code);
        if (resp.items) {
          for(var t in resp.items) {
            display_card(t.getPrice(), t.getComment());
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('API is not ready!');
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=api_init"></script>
```

using API Explorer call to this method returns next:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "5629499534213120",
   "price": 55,
   "comment": "ggggg",
   "kind": "transaction#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "5639445604728832",
   "price": 55,
   "comment": "gggg",
   "kind": "transaction#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "5649391675244544",
   "price": 55,
   "comment": "ggggg",
   "kind": "transaction#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "5659313586569216",
   "price": 55,
   "comment": "yhuy",
   "kind": "transaction#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "5722646637445120",
   "price": 5522,
   "comment": "yhuyhhhgffg",
   "kind": "transaction#resourcesItem"
  }
 ],
 "kind": "transaction#resources",
 "etag": "\"...\""
}
```

and it the output in console is:

```
listTransactions resp: false code: undefined
```

So what is wrong in js and more important question is how can I figure out what is wrong for other methods as I used to develop android apps and I'm new to js.

Comment: [doc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest) for RpcRequest says ` If the response is not JSON, this field will be false`. Soo I tried to log a raw response and here what it is `{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Unknown Error","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"internalError","message":"Unknown Error"}]}}` but what does it mean ??

Comment: BTW XHR is `"https://<project-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/rpc` but API exploorer do requests to `https://<project-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/<api-name>/<version>/<?returned-type?>/<param>`. Sould it be like this ?